# Network solution does not accept an AWS machine as nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have set up an AWS EC2 machine as a (BIND) nameserver and I am in the process of making it secondary for several domains we manage. This is cool for all our domain name vendors (e.g. IT-NIC, Marcaria) except Network Solution. I have so far been unable to make their panel to accept the AWS machine as nameserver - the reported reason is that the nameserver "does not exist or is behind a firewall". The machine itself is already acting as secondary NS for several domains and answering queries regularly.

In an attempt to make NetSol accept the machine I enabled ping, zone transfers and set an MX for the zone the NS is in (which is of course silly, but one never knows). All to no avail, and Google's not helping.

Has anybody confronted, and hopefully solved, a similar problem?

Advanced thanks.

**EDIT4**
As it turns out, this has nothing to do with networking: the error message from netsol (reiterated in their answer to a support ticket) threw me wildly offtrack for a while.

Registrars, among them netsol, require that new nameservers be present in one (of several) whois or RDAP databases. For .com (and .net?) the reference is https://rdap.verisign.com. (https://www.verisign.com/en_US/domain-names/registration-data-access-protocol/index.xhtml)

I have been unable to locate a way for the general public to insert data into Verisign (RDAP), but that's something registrars can do (we do that for .it domains, for instance).

NETSOL has (used to have? the URL of the FAQ I found point elsewhere these days) have such a procedure which **is not exposed through the partner portal** which is what I have to use. What the partner *does* expose is a panel to add a 'new' or 'existing' nameserver. But neither worked for me (I can only assume that the backend procedure to register a new NS is buggy)

To fix the SNAFU, a different domain was created at a different registrar (opensrs, which is backed up by twocows), using their procedure to register a nameserver and rescuing the day. Strangely enough, netsol picks up a nameserver that's registered through opensrs/twocows but is unable to do the same for NS registered through Marcaria - go figure.

So I will accept t3ln3t solution, which correctly points to the cause. Getting it to work can require much more devious ways, see above.

Comment: "that I do not own the reverse resolution " I know no relevant DNS troubleshooting tool that cares about that. At worst you get a warning, but this kind of discrepancy has 0 operational consequences on DNS resolution, so it shouldn't ever be considered an error. Now, besides your provider, and without clear error explanation, noone can really know, except by having the same case as you, what is exactly the problem here. Had you given the name in question, people could have tested for you, but you didn't. "or is behind a firewall" may mean you filter out TCP for example, which indeed is wrong.

Comment: I have added the machine name and firewall details in the question text.

Comment: In many ways (such as this one) Network Solutions is still stuck in the distant past, and I would not recommend them for registering or managing domains. They probably wouldn't even still be in this business if they didn't have a large number of corporate clients that have been paying them since the 1990s (and are probably still paying 1990s prices).

Comment: They just replied to the support ticket I had opened doubling down on the - totally wrong - "unreachable nameserver" explanation. That is the support level offered to partners.

Comment: "Some registrars, among them netsol, (others, apparently, do not care) require that new nameservers be present in one (of several) whois or RDAP databases."  that is incorrect. All registrars require that, because it is a feature of the way things work, so host objects have to be registered at the registry (and this has nothing to do with whois or RDAP), otherwise the registry won't accept the change. However what most registrars do is that everything is transparent: when you change your domain to use nameserver X, they will automatically create host object X at registry and you see nothing.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek After thinking about it, I believe you are right about whois NS records being mandatory (that's where the root nameservers build their zones from methinks - dunno if it's the only route though). Netsol (partner portal) appears to be unable to do that on its own, while being able to pick pre-existing whois NS (domain') records. It wasn't picking up the one entered through Marcaria, though, which is puzzling. I edited the question to reflect this exchange.

Comment: " I believe you are right about whois NS records being mandatory" It is not phrased correctly, but I am in this business (domain name) since more than 20 years, so I can vouch for certain things :-) If you want the technical explanations, have a read at RFC 5730, 5731 and 5732, EPP is the protocol used by registrars to do operations at registries. "(that's where the root nameservers build their zones from methinks - dunno if it's the only route though)." that is not it also, or not correctly phrased, but too long to explain in a comment. Hosts are objects in registry database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Network Solutions you need to register the name server before it can be used with a domain. The process is fairly straight forward however it can take up to 72 hours for the newly registered name server to be 'active' and usable.

Log in to your account. ...
In the My Products & Services tab under the My Domain Names section, click Edit DNS.
On the next page in the grey box on the right side, click Domain Name Server (DNS).
Enter your name servers in the space provided.

also, if you put a support ticket in with AWS, you can get custom reverse entries made. Or you can do this yourself with Route-53 (AWS dns).
Nifty for mail servers...

Comment: As per my second edit I am entering through the partner portal - so the UI is different. For each domain, I have a "manage nameservers" section, where I can insert nameservers either as an "existing host" (name only) or "new host" (name+IP). Which one I should use is unclear (the former, most likely: we are already using other privately managed NSs). In any case, neither works for this host.

Comment: I have not personally used Network Solutions' Partner Portal however their documentation says:
https://partners.networksolutions.com/en_US/help/how-to/create-new-host.html

Once you add a new host, and it resolves you should be able to use it as a name server for your domains.

Comment: "The process is fairly straight forward however it can take up to 72 hours for the newly registered name server to be 'active' and usable." Where does that come from? Registering a nameserver, that is an host object, at registry, by a registrar, is a synchronous EPP command, so it is effective immediately. That is immediately when the registrar sends the command to the registry of course.

Comment: This was indeed the root cause ("The nameserver does not exist or is behind a firewall", sheesh). Solving it requires more footwork (for me, at least, as it appears the partner portal is broken). See edited post.